# Java Applet - Unable to change default platform encoding to some other

Tags: java, encoding, applet, lotus-domino, osx-leopard

I am facing an encoding problem (I guess) when I try to upload a file with file name having swedish charachters Ӧ Ӓ å. Applet works fine when I upload a file on Windows but not on Mac OS.

The filename gets messed up when print it on the server side, which is a Domino server, and shows boxes on Mac but When I set the encoding to UTF-8 by `new String(filename.getBytes("utf-8"))` it shows `?` on both Win and Mac.

UPDATED:

Following are the code snippets:

Setting the request params and posting

```
...
request.setParameter("Name", tmpAtt.getFileName());
...

HttpURLConnection connection ...
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + boundary);

if (os == null) os = connection.getOutputStream();
```

Setting param for filename and Inputstream

```
request.setParameter(fileUploadFieldName, tmpAtt.getFilePath(), fi);

public void setParameter(String name, String filename, InputStream is) throws IOException {
    boundary();
    writeName(name);
    write("; charset=utf-8; filename=\"");
    write(filename);
    write('"');
    newline();
    write("Content-Type:");
    String type = connection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename);
    if (type == null) type = "application/octet-stream";
    writeln(type);
    newline();
    pipe(is, os);
    newline();
}
```

At the end posting to the server

```
public InputStream post() throws IOException {
    boundary();
    writeln("--");
    printOS(os);
    os.close();
    InputStream iis = connection.getInputStream();
    printIS(iis);
    return iis;
}
```

Getting this output when writing the bytes on OutputStream to send the request. And name looks fine to me.

```
------------------------------hxre3intl6yy-17eufpccwtxc89pbvyg0iwe3i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Name

Räpörå.log
------------------------------hxre3intl6yy-17eufpccwtxc89pbvyg0iwe3i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Name2


------------------------------hxre3intl6yy-17eufpccwtxc89pbvyg0iwe3i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="APPROVALSTATUS
```

What could be the problem.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java strings are always internally encoded as UTF-16, but this is not relevant to your problem, and the attempt to "set the encoding" of a string is inherently wrong.

Encodings are used to *translate* between Strings and bytes. Your problem is that at some point where this is done, you are not specifying an encoding, so Java uses the platform default encoding.

Since the filesystem API is String-based, the problem cannot be at that end, so the `filename` String is probably corruped at the point where you retrieve it from the user - or because there is another instance of wrongly and pointlessly trying to "set the encoding" of a Java String.

The encoding settings in eclipse are only relevant for your source code or other files that are part of your project.

Comment: I tried to encode it to utf-8 but did not work, before I was not encoding anything at all. Corruption of filename string seems logical but when I print the value just before the post, it seems fine.

Comment: @user330281: It may be that the problem is at the filesystem side after all. Try running the problem with the command line parameter -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 (configure that in the eclipse run configuration). All in all, it seems non-ASCII characters in filenames are still problematic. I just recently noticed non-ASCII filenames getting corrupted while simply copying files between a Windows PC and a Linux NAS.

Comment: thx. Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using the applet in browser and I guess then I would not need to put the above parameter in run config of eclipse, what could be the workaround for the applet in browser. should i create the jar by giving the above param as command arg or should it be the param with in the <applet> tag? another thing is that i am sending request to domino server and hope it would not have any issue...

Comment: @user330281: I don't think you can define system properties , but now it looks like you omitted the most important part of your setup: you're not using Java's filesystem API at all, are you? If the file is written to that domino server than that's actuall most likely where you're having issues.

Comment: but i dont understand why this is working when I upload the weird named file from windows. I am using Java's FS api to create temp file(s), as far as this filename issue is concerned, I am NOT using. I am just setting the param (filename) in the request (HttpRequest) and then clearing off the stream to post... that is it, seems simple but it is driving me crazy...

Comment: @user330281: ah, now we're getting somewhere. My guess is that somehow you end up using the platform default encoding when you set the param in the HttpRequest, that's why it depends on the OS. ANd either there's a problem with how you're setting it, or Domino doesn't process it correctly. I suggest you add that part of the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the encoding scheme to `ISO-8859-1`.

The above mentioned `write("Content-Type:");` method was something like this:

```
1. write(String s){
2. os.write(s.getBytes());
3. }
```

And I just changed the 2nd line to `os.write(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))`

It did not work with `UTF-8`, I don't know why???

the scheme was being changed somewhere to `MacRoman` because when I added the ISO-8859-1 schema to this (as mentioned above) line `request.setParameter("Name", new String(tmpAtt.getFileName().getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));`, the `Name` was being garbled at the end.

But I could not understand why UTF-8 did not work and why the scheme was being changed somewhere in the middle???

thank-you

Comment: new String() uses the platform default encoding. As I said: trying to "convert" a Java String to a different encoding is fundamentally wrong. As for why UTF-8 did not work: the filename is sent as part of the HTTP headers of the request, and HTTP headers are implicitly ISO- 8859-1 as mandated by the standard. So your changed write() method is now standard-compliant.